# nme for linux target setup fails on debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I'm trying to run

```
haxelib run nme setup linux
```

To set up NME for the Linux target on my Debian box. Actually Linux MINT Debian Edition, but that shouldn't matter. However, I get the following output:

```
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch
Called from ? line 1
Called from InstallTool.hx line 579
Called from setup/PlatformSetup.hx line 440
Called from setup/PlatformSetup.hx line 474
Called from setup/PlatformSetup.hx line 1410
Called from helpers/ProcessHelper.hx line 133
Called from helpers/ProcessHelper.hx line 169
Uncaught exception - Error running: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch gcc-multilib g++-multilib []
```

I also tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

But I get

```
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-multiarch
```

Is this an Ubuntu specific package?

Edit: I got this to work eventually, without installing that package or any other. Unfortunatly I don't remember what it was I did. If someone finds this and has the same problem give this question some attention and I will try again..

Comment: There is no `ia32-libs-multiarch` on Debian: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ia32-libs-multiarch

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. The question is why does haxelib try to install it then, and what should it install instead? I can leave the second half of that question, namely what should be installed instead, on here in case someone knows. Once I know that I can take it to the haxelib developers and ask them the first part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ia32-libs-multiarch` on Debian, however I had a look at the Ubuntu repositories, and `ia32-libs-multiarch` is just a metapackage (an empty package that depends on others).

There's no description for this package, but I believe it is just a metapackage that tries to pull everything the developers think they might need some day, or will never need and are too lazy to check.

Here is the list of packages which are installable on Debian:

> bluez-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
>   gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-oxygen
>   gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs ibus-gtk libacl1 libaio1 libao4 libasound2
>   libasound2-plugins libasyncns0 libattr1 libaudio2
>   libcanberra-gtk-module libcap2 libcapi20-3 libcups2 libcupsimage2
>   libcurl3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libesd0 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6
>   libgail-common libgconf-2-4 libgdbm3 libgettextpo0 libglapi-mesa
>   libglu1-mesa libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-port0 libgtk2.0-0 libmpg123-0
>   libncursesw5 libnspr4 libnss3 libodbc1 libopenal1
>   libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-opengl
>   libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql
>   libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4
>   libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 librsvg2-common libsane libsdl-image1.2
>   libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-net1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl1.2debian
>   libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++5 libstdc++6 libxaw7 libxml2 libxp6
>   libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxtst6 odbcinst1debian2 xaw3dg

There is no `libssl0.9.8` and `libpulsedsp` on Debian, but I really
doubt you'll ever need them.

Either install them all and remove the part that tries to pull `ia32-libs-multiarch` from `InstallTool.hx`, `setup/PlatformSetup.hx` or `helpers/ProcessHelper.hx`, or contact the developers and ask them why their package would need such things as **Qt libs** and **Gtk+ themes** at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

If your mint distro is based on the debian testing you can open the multi-arch support by just:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

so you can install the 32bit software and all the ia32-lib can be installed just by the `apt-get install` command.